# JSF 2.2.10: The f:ajax execute="@this" doesn't process h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra, selectbooleancheckbox

I was using the Wildfly with JSF version 2.2.8-jboss.org version of this server. After migrating to JBoss EAP 6.3.x, packaging version of the JSF 2.2.9, 2.2.10 or 2.2.11 is happening the following:

If I use the attribute `execute` as below, the map `#{mBean.mapa}` is no longer updated.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkAtividade" value="#{mBean.mapa[atividade]}" title="#{atividade.nome}">
   <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render=":form:panelBotoes" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

I had to change to `execute="@form"` to get it to function.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkAtividade" value="#{mBean.mapa[atividade]}" title="#{atividade.nome}">
   <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":form:panelBotoes" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Does anyone know why? In newer versions of the JSF, was there a change in behavior `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` with `<f:ajax>`? This looks like a bug.

Comment: You can always check the mojarra releasenotes

Comment: I've checked the latest release notes, but did not find mention of this problem. What is strange is that the version of the JSF used by Wildfly (2.2.8-jboss.org) this problem does not exist.